# How to get title in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I sit all day and don’t understand why it doesn't work.
I have X-CSRF-TOKEN in the header.
How do I get it? I tried it in different ways and no one method works.

Below is my **Vue.js**

```
    <script>

    import axios from "axios";

    export default {

      name: "UploadFiles",

      data() {
        return{
          file: ""
        }
      },

      methods:{

        selectFile(){
          this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0]
        },

        async sendFile() {


          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', this.file);

          await axios.post('/user/uploadImages', formData)


        }


      }


    }


    </script>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085493/getting-data-from-response-headers-in-axios ? Although, I'm very confused by the title of this question as it seems to not relate to the question at all.

Comment: @sno2 this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
}
```